# Why the input [] is not submitted?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have these checkboxes :

```
<input name="linkStyle" type="checkbox" name="style[]" value="Style1" />
<input name="linkStyle" type="checkbox" name="style[]" value="Style2" />
<input name="linkStyle" type="checkbox" name="style[]" value="Style3" />
```

and this jQuery function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[name=linkStyle]').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#browseForm').submit(); 
        });                 
    });
</script>
```

but in fact it doesnt send to the server the style[] array trought the form. Why? And how can I fix this trouble? Tried also removing e.preventDefault(); but nothing change...

Comment: Why does your input have two `name`s?

Comment: Wait, you're listening for `click`s on the checkboxes, *preventing the default action*, and submitting the form?  Wouldn't preventing that default action *stop the checkbox from being checked to begin with*?  Maybe these should be submit buttons to begin with...

Comment: @Charles : I don't understand what do you mean?

Comment: you really should run your html through a validator.

Comment: @kwichz, calling `preventDefault()` stops the event's default action from occuring.  When a checkbox is clicked, the default action is to change the state of the check.  By preventing that default action, the checkbox *never gets checked*!  (This is beyond the `name` attribute issue.)  If you are trying to submit a form when a checkbox is checked, perhaps the checkboxes shouldn't be checkboxes, but should be submit buttons instead, and you should represent their checked-ness in another way.

Comment: @Wes : do you speak about the 2 name attribute or there are others errors? Seems ok the rest...

Comment: @kwichz yes that. It would help you find things quicker thats all.

Comment: @Charles : uhm...which way? Can you give to me an example?

Comment: @kwichz, your code here isn't specific to the thing you're doing, so I can't really give you user interface advice. :) If you're trying to represent a list of possible states and allow the user to toggle them on or off, then perhaps a list of activated things with deactivated buttons and a list of deactivated things with a list of activated buttons might be a better way to present the information.  Just a stab in the dark.  Having the form submit when a checkbox is checked is going to surprise your users, and users don't like surprises. A form submit on button press isn't a surprise.

Comment: Uhm...I use this strategy to do a sort of "filter" : check it out here http://www.gabbatracklistworld.com/index.php?explore=browse, pressing on the checkboxes; is not so horrible imo :)

Comment: @kwichz, modern implementations of filtering tend to use ajax and dynamic page updating instead of a whole-page submit and refresh.

Comment: Yeah I know... but for this kind I prefeer this manner :) Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try --

**HTML**

```
<input class="linkStyle" type="checkbox" name="style[]" value="Style1" />
<input class="linkStyle" type="checkbox" name="style[]" value="Style2" />
<input class="linkStyle" type="checkbox" name="style[]" value="Style3" />
```

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.linkStyle').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#browseForm').submit(); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have two `name` attributes on one element.  They conflict, and you end up overwriting one with the other.

Answer (score 3):

You have the `name` attribute twice on your inputs.

Answer (score 3):

like it has been stated you have two names so I would suggest change the one name to a class like this

```
<input class="linkStyle" type="checkbox" name="style[]" value="Style1" />
<input class="linkStyle" type="checkbox" name="style[]" value="Style2" />
<input class="linkStyle" type="checkbox" name="style[]" value="Style3" />
```

then you can target the class

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.linkStyle').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#browseForm').submit(); 
        });                 
    });
</script>
```